# Depth sorting multidimensional array based on nested value OR elevated value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So I just had one of those "this will DEFINITELY work" moments of excitement only to be followed with severe disappointment.  I've been trying to figure out how to sort an array of arrays containing arrays for a little bit now and figured I'd see if SO wanted to help me :)

Data structure:

```
var array = [{ name: "sunday",   data: [{x: 5, y: 7}, { x: 6, y: 12 }, { x: 6, y: 22 }]},
             { name: "tuesday",  data: {x: 1, y: 15}},
             { name: "monday",   data: {x: 3, y: 25}},
             { name: "thursday", data: {x: 7, y: 5}},
             { name: "friday",   data: {x: 2, y: 2}}];
```

Snippet of sorrow:

```
function compare(a,b) {
    var c = undefined != a.data.length ? Math.max.apply(Math,a.data.map(function(o){return o.y;})) : a.y;
    var d = undefined != b.data.length ? Math.max.apply(Math,b.data.map(function(o){return o.y;})) : b.y;

    if (c > d)
        return -1;
    if (c < d)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

So the idea is fairly basic, I want to sort an array based on the max y value.  Problem is I have a variable amount of x/y pairs for each array entry...so I need to compare based on possible deep(er) nested values.

Essentially the comparer checks if data is an array or not, if it is it uses some math illusions and pops out the max value of the y's contained within...if it's not it just takes the y value.

That works.  So does the extremely basic `if a > b return -1` pattern I currently have implemented in the comparer.  But SURPRISE...together they hate me.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Failure in action - http://jsfiddle.net/TpF8g/

Comment: I would avoid doing this: `undefined != a.data.length` Just one typo, and you've potentially redefined `undefined`.

Comment: @BlueSkies so you're saying be very VEERRRYYY careful, right? ;)

Comment: Instead of `a.y` and `b.y` you need `a.data.y` and `b.data.y`

Comment: @BlueSkies ha, I feel like an idiot.  I'm sure that'll work...I'll test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing a `data` property:

```
function compare(a,b) {
    var c = undefined != a.data.length ? Math.max.apply(Math,a.data.map(function(o){return o.y;})) : a.data.y;
    var d = undefined != b.data.length ? Math.max.apply(Math,b.data.map(function(o){return o.y;})) : b.data.y;

    if (c > d)
        return -1;
    if (c < d)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

A shorter version could be:

```
function compare(a,b) {

  function byY(d1, d2){ return d1.y - d2.y; }
  // quick and dirty
  var c = a.data.length ? a.data.sort(byY)[a.data.length-1].y : a.data.y;
  var d = b.data.length ? b.data.sort(byY)[b.data.length-1].y : b.data.y;

  return d - c;
}
```

Comment: I feel like checking a.data.length is dangerous - what if the object has a length property?

Comment: The alternatives are using the `Array.isArray(obj)` function for newer browsers or the old fashioned `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";`
`instanceof` is not safe either.

Comment: @linstantnoodles it won't have a length property, but its a good point.

Comment: @MarcoCI Your shorter version would have been great if I needed to actually sort the nested x/y pairs but unfortunately I can't.  This is for a graph and that throws everything out of whack :P.

Answer (score 2):

So you're trying to sort a list of objects based on a property called `y`, and each of those objects may have a variable number of `y`. Furthermore, if there are > 1 `y`, you want to consider the maximum.

Here's how I would write the compare function:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    // Get our maximum y value
    var getMaxY = function(data) {
        // Check if array
        if (data instanceof Array) {
            // Sort our inner array
            data.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.y - b.y;
            });
            // Get the last one
            return data[data.length - 1].y;
        }
        // Else return y
        return data.y;
    }
    // Compare the maximum y values
    return getMaxY(a.data) - getMaxY(b.data);
}
```